# RobotScript - Catch Python Code Exception

Tags: robotframework

We have a following code in Python

```
def function1()
    ...........
    raise Exception ..
    ...............
    return 0
```

Robot script:

```
   ${STATUS}=    function1
```

Can anyone please let me know how in Robot script we can catch the return code / exception and branch accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) will return a boolean true/false did the enclose keyword succeed.
[Run Keyword And Ignore Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error) returns a tuple of two values - the 1st is the string "PASS" or "FAIL" depending did your keyword succeed or not; the second - the keyword's return value if it passed, or any error messages if not.

Thus surround your keyword with one of these 2 - it really boils down to do you care about the returned value in success or the error in failure - and work with the returned values.

```
${passed}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    function1
Run Keyword If    ${passed}     Action When Passed    ELSE    Different Action

${rc}    ${msg}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    function1
Run Keyword If    "${rc}" == 'PASS'    Log    The keyword returned the value: ${msg}    
   ...            ELSE                 Log    The keyword failed with the message: ${msg}
```